# How to pass value in select UITableViewCell Row

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json, uitableview

I have `UITableViewCell`, cell indexing category wise and expand cell click on header, and load data by JSON. I want to select cell and pass data another view controller. I try to many times but pass data only first cell. I clicked another cell so this condition pass data first cell. Can't send particular cell data. How it possible . please help.

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSError *error;

    NSMutableDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves  error:&error];

    NSArray *statuses = [json objectForKey:@"status"];
    names=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[statuses valueForKey:@"business_category_name"]];
    business_details_array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[statuses valueForKey:@"business_details"]];

    for (int i=0; i<[names count]; i++) {
        [arrayForBool addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
    }

    [self.tabel_view reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
     return names.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if ([[arrayForBool objectAtIndex:section] boolValue]) {
        return [[business_details_array objectAtIndex:section] count];
    }
    else
        return 0;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 70;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    UIView *sectionHeaderView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width,70)];

    sectionHeaderView.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];

    sectionHeaderView.tag=section;

    UIView *sectionsubHeaderView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width,60)];

    sectionsubHeaderView.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];

    UIImageView *arrow=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,60, 60)];

    [arrow setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"]];

    UILabel *Lbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 0,tableView.frame.size.width-60, 60)];

    Lbl.text=[names objectAtIndex:section];

    Lbl.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

    [sectionsubHeaderView addSubview:arrow];

    [sectionsubHeaderView addSubview:Lbl];

    [sectionHeaderView addSubview:sectionsubHeaderView];

    UITapGestureRecognizer  *headerTapped   = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(sectionHeaderTapped:)];

    [sectionHeaderView addGestureRecognizer:headerTapped];

    return  sectionHeaderView;
}

- (void)sectionHeaderTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:gestureRecognizer.view.tag];
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        BOOL collapsed  = [[arrayForBool objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] boolValue];
        for (int i=0; i<[names count]; i++) {
            if (indexPath.section==i) {
                [arrayForBool replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:!collapsed]];
            }
        }
        [self.tabel_view reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:gestureRecognizer.view.tag] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MemberTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ht"];
    if (cell==nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Cell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    NSString*title_str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[business_details_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] valueForKey:@"name"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.title.text= title_str;
    [titles addObject:title_str];
    NSLog(@"get %@",titles);

    cell.email.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[business_details_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] valueForKey:@"email"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    //[emailary addObject:cell.email.text];

    cell.address_lbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[business_details_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] valueForKey:@"address"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    //[adrsary addObject:cell.address_lbl.text];

    cell.phone_lbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[business_details_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] valueForKey:@"phone"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    // [phoneary addObject:cell.phone_lbl.text];

    cell.web_lbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[business_details_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] valueForKey:@"website"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    //[websiteary addObject:cell.web_lbl.text];

    cell.sens_lbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[business_details_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] valueForKey:@"member_since"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    //[sensary addObject:cell.sens_lbl.text];

    cell.des_lbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[business_details_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] valueForKey:@"des"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    //[desary addObject:cell.des_lbl.text];

    NSData* imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[business_details_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] valueForKey:@"img_url"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]]];

    UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

    cell.image_view.image =image;
    //[images addObject:cell.image_view.image];

    return  cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [arrayForBool replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.section withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];

    [self.tabel_view reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showRecipeDetail"])
    {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tabel_view indexPathForSelectedRow];
        member_details *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.hello = [titles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Kumawat are u sing Navigation controller for pushing next view?

Comment: @KoushikGounder yes proper sing next view controller

Comment: So u need to click on a cell then a larger view should appear with the details of that particular cell am I correct ?
Correct me If I am wrong So that I can provide perfect solution

Comment: yes you are correct

Comment: Try my answer 
if u find any difficulty comment here

Answer (score 1):

As you have directly joined segue from tableview, it's not proper way to do that. Instead of you have to joined segue by controller to controller. So before getting proper selected row index, your view controller push fast and you are always getting 0 index.

Instead of writing logic in `prepareForSegue`, you can do the same stuff in `didSelect` method of `UITablView`.

For that you have to find your destination view controller from storyboard. And set the data to required property.

**EDIT**

Remove your prepare segure logic and do this in didSelect

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     [arrayForBool replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.section withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];

     [self.tabel_view reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

     UIStoryboard *storyboard = 
        [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" 
                                  bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
     YourDestinationVC *vc =[[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourDestinationVC"]; //@"YourDestinationVC" is storyboardID for your destination view controller
     vc.hello = [titles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     [[self navigationController] pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

Here is screenshot :

[image]

Comment: @A.Kumawat also remove segue from storyboard. Instedof give stroyboardID to viewcontroller. And use this storyboardID in code.

Comment: @A.Kumawat Let me know if you still facing issue.

Comment: error show bellow:- Doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'YourDestinationVC''

Comment: @"YourDestinationVC" is storyboardID for your destination view controller

Comment: You have to replace it with your viewcontroller

Comment: You can set Identifier to your UIViewController in the Xcode's Identity Inspector!

Comment: Please wait I trying

Answer (score 0):

Try this remove prepare for `prepareForSegue` and in `didselectrowatindexpath` add.

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [arrayForBool replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.section withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];

    [self.tabel_view reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

    member_details *destViewController = [[member_details alloc]init];
    destViewController.hello = [titles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:destViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: In this no identifier set?

Comment: This is by doing it Programmatically not using story board

Comment: Just do as I say create a viewcontroller (tempVC)
In tempVC.m
`
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
}`

Import tempVC in your tableviewcontrollers .h file
In your didselectrowatindex path 

create an object for that 

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

tempVC *destViewController = [[tempVC alloc]init];

 [[self navigationController] pushViewController:destViewController animated:YES];

 }

Comment if you see greenColor after clicking the cell

Comment: same as follow your code but can't pass data. how it possible please help

Comment: Did you get the the green color view?

Comment: Yes I get Green color view

Comment: Super Ji I'll send you the proper answer

Comment: Your tempVC.h file
https://ghostbin.com/paste/fsu4a

Your tempVC.m
https://ghostbin.com/paste/h2kgc

Your didselectrowatindexpath method
https://ghostbin.com/paste/oumhq

Comment: Using @property u can also send dictionries and arrays also customize the tempVC as u need

Comment: Verifying my answer and up voting will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You should create your segues between viewcontrollers.

Do not create segue from cell to viewcontrollers.

Then you should call

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showRecipeDetail" sender:self];
```

after updating the table in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: I added this line but can't pass. how it possible

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showRecipeDetail" sender:[YOUR_ARRAY objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showRecipeDetail"])
    {
        member_details *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.hello = sender;

    }
}
```